# Page background gradient change on mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, linear-gradients

I have a page with a gradient applied on page load via CSS and would like to animate the page alternating the gradient colors and degree (linear-gradient - 4 different colors all degrade to white) on mouse move. 
If I use only 2 colors it works fine. But I want to get a random color from an array on mouse move but it flickers. Any solution for that?

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjpramos/g137be71/)

```
var colorArr = ['#dfa7ca', '#f7c2b3', '#bae0f1', '#a6d6cb'];
var grFrom = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArr.length)];
var grTo = '#FFFFFF';

$("body").mousemove(function( e ) {
  var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  var grFrom = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArr.length)];//get a new random color
  var xy = (x + y) / 8;
  var w = $(this).width(),
  pct = 360*(+e.pageX)/w,
  bg = "linear-gradient(" + xy + "deg,"+grFrom+","+grTo+")";
  $("body").css("background-image", bg);
});
```

Comment: Try setting a `transition` css rule for your `body`. Something like `transition: background-image 0.5s ease;`. Edit: This is just a suggestion I didnt try it.

Comment: I think its normal to flicker, because you change the whole gradiant, I don't really get what you want to achieve, maybe you want some kind of animation? try to sue transition on background.

Comment: You're selecting the color in the `mousemove` event, so every time the mouse moves, the color changes, which is a lot. So you want the color to change less often - when?

Comment: I've tried the transition rule but I think I get the same flickering effect. Yes, if I could change the color only when user moves mouse to corners of the screen would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your handler in [_.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#throttle), and play with the millis, until you have an acceptable result.

```
var colorArr = ['#dfa7ca', '#f7c2b3', '#bae0f1', '#a6d6cb'];
var grFrom = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArr.length)];
var grTo = '#FFFFFF';


var wrapped = _.throttle(function(e){
  var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  var grFrom = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArr.length)];
  var xy = (x + y) / 8;
  var w = $(this).width(),
  pct = 360*(+e.pageX)/w,
  bg = "linear-gradient(" + xy + "deg,"+grFrom+","+grTo+")";
  $("body").css("background-image", bg);
},50)//Try increasing/decreasing this value to see the differrence


$("body").mousemove(wrapped);
```

See: 
https://jsfiddle.net/g137be71/24/

**Update:** Actually I had pasted a wrong link. This is for `throttle`.
https://jsfiddle.net/g137be71/82/

Comment: Thanks @marinos-an. Your solution is mostly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to inlcude jQueryUI and then you can use `animate()` to change the color. Please check here:

https://jqueryui.com/animate/

So you should use something like this:

```
 $( "#selector" ).animate({
          backgroundColor: bg
        }, 10 );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963059/jquery-animate-div-background-color-gradient. I'm not pretty sure, animate will do the stuff

Comment: I just tried to help him:) . not sure 100% that will work.

Comment: CSS transitions would work just fine here. There's no need to include another library.