# jQuery-UI animation, background, linear-gradient

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, background, linear-gradients

I wanted to animated, changing background colors with jQuery-UI, but not only color, linear-gradient. It doesn't work, I tried to change "backgroundColor" for only background, because in css linear-gradient can only be amplied to a "background", but in jQuery-UI only background doesn't work.

```
$(".btn").hover(Change_Color, Change_Color_Back)

function Change_Color() {
    $(".square").animate({
        backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #0265cd, #1790fb)",
        color: "white"
    },300);
    $(".btn").css("background", "#f2f3f4");
    $(".btn").css("color", "#3d3d3d");
}

function Change_Color_Back() {
    $(".square").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#f2f3f4",
        color: "#3d3d3d"
    },300)
    $(".btn").css("background", "");
    $(".btn").css("color", "");
}
```

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963059/jquery-animate-div-background-color-gradient