# JQuery - background color fade out animation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, background, jquery-animate

I have th following script

```
 $("button#submit").click(function () {
 $("tr[data-id='" + lastRefId + "']").css("background-color", "#8aabf0");
 $("tr[data-id='" + lastRefId + "']").animate({ backgroundColor: "white"}, 'slow');
});
```

It's a simple script that should change the backgrund to the color above and than change it back to the previous color (white).
The first line works, but the second doesn't.

Why and how should I fix it?

Comment: From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties): For example, width, height, or left can be animated **but background-color cannot** be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used)

Comment: or if you are already using jquery UI, no need to add jQuery.color() plugin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery background animate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701156/jquery-background-animate)

Comment: you need query ui for color animation support, but you should Do this with CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery don't support background color in animation method... by itself
You have to download the jquery-Color.js from the [jQuery site](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/24/jquery-color-2-1-0/) and append it after the jQuery source code, then you can use the animation() with background color
The first line works, because you used CSS method and background-color as a CSS property haven't any problem, In second line you used animation...
and you have to write the css properties as an animation argument in camel-case; 
for example `background-color`, must to be `backgroundColor`